# How To Show Multiple Value From String Using PHP

Tags: php, sql, select

i want to get multiple value from string, this is my example code :

```
<?php
$theloai= $row['theloai'];
echo $theloai
?>
```

Inside row `theloai` have this value in one column:

```
1,2
```

If I display value from column **theloai** it in the usual way, it will produce the following result:

```
<a href="">1,2</a>
```

I want to display it like: :

```
<a href="1">1</a> <a href="2">2</a>
```

Please give for me example code

Comment: `explode()` will be your friend - As you have tagged `mysql` I guess the data is coming from mysql - And here is the problem.. do not store comma separated values into the db but think about normalization of your data

Comment: Well I will check it again, thank you !!!

Answer (score 0):

You should create array from your string with [explode()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php) and iterate over it:

```
<?php

$theloai = '1,2';
$theloai = explode(',', $theloai);

foreach ($theloai as $v) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $v; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

In your case:

```
$theloai = explode(',', $row['theloai']);
foreach ($theloai as $v) { ?>
    <a href="<?php echo $v; ?>"><?php echo $v; ?></a>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: @VõHữuNhân Notice: You can accept and upvote this answer. Also notice that your question is such a simple and some research would give you the right answer : )